# Error in deploying Java app to Elastic Beanstalk - error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rest

I have developed a REST API using Java. It works perfectly on local computer and it is compiled with Java 11.0.2. It is also using `Hibernate`.

When I try to upload this to the `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`, it always fail with a severe error. I downloaded the log files and the `eb-engine.log` says the following

```
2021/08/06 07:36:01.851410 [ERROR] update processes [web healthd cfn-hup nginx] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
2021/08/06 07:36:01.851423 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [web healthd cfn-hup nginx] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
```

I am not using any specific configuration in my Java app. The `war` file is a clean build directly from `netbeans IDE`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Spoontech: Not at all. I have no idea how to fix it too, for sometime i didnt work on it so dont know the current situation.